# Summed-area table vs Integral image?

Tags: opencv, object-recognition, face-detection

I have been going through few research papers around face recognition and I came across two texture extraction algorithms :

1. **Summed-area table** by Crow et al. ("Summed-area tables for texture mapping", 1984)
2. **Integral image** by Viola et al. (e.g. "Robust Real-time Object Detection", 2002)

Apologizes if I'm wrong, I found that generating texture map in both these algorithms are same.

> i.e., Texture map $I(x,y)$ = Sum of all gray level intensity values
>   who lies left and above $i(x,y)$ of the original image.

Please clarify me, **what is the main difference between these two algorithms**?

Answer (score 1):

The Sum-area table (SAT) was introduced in computer graphics, and as far as I know, was popularized in computer vision and image processing under the name Integral image.

Apart from a larger genericity of the SAT to objects of dimensions different to that of images, the concepts are the same to me.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same concept. Summed Area Tables are typically called Integral Images in the image processing domain. In fact, the Wikipedia entry has the following line:

*A summed-area table is a data structure and algorithm for quickly and efficiently generating the sum of values in a rectangular subset of a grid. In the image processing domain, it is also known as an integral image.*[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed-area_table)